# Running executale file (gfortran) in Matlab on MacOS

Tags: matlab, executable, gfortran

Does any one know how to run an executable file (gfortran) from Matlab on Mac ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So is it from Matlab or you want to run in Matlab? For what purpose? How did you compile the code? Did you compile it on the same computer? Did you try to run it? What happened when you tried it? See [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 'system' command in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850086/how-to-use-system-command-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

See link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

If you are trying to execute an already-compiled fortran code, try system('./script.o') or whatever your executable name is.